# Fill missing line numbers into file using sed / awk / bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a (tab-delimited) file where the first "word" on each line is the line number. However, some line numbers are missing. I want to insert new lines (with corresponding line number) so that throughout the file, the number printed on the line matches the actual line number. (This is for later consumption into readarray with cut/awk to get the line after the line number.)

I've written this logic in python and tested it works, however I need to run this in an environment that doesn't have python. The actual file is about 10M rows. Is there a way to represent this logic using sed, awk, or even just plain shell / bash?

```py
linenumre = re.compile(r"^\d+")
i = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    i = i + 1
    linenum = int(linenumre.findall(line)[0])

    while (i < linenum):
        print(i)
        i = i + 1

    print(line, end='')
```

test file looks like:

```
1   foo 1
2   bar 1
4   qux 1
6   quux    1
9       2
10  fun 2
```

expected output like:

```
1   foo 1
2   bar 1
3
4   qux 1
5
6   quux    1
7
8
9       2
10  fun 2
```

Comment: 10 million rows is not a job for the shell, it's not that It can't do it but it will take forever to finish :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this, with `awk`:

```
awk '{while(++ln!=$1){print ln}}1' input.txt
```

Explanation, as a multiline script:

```
{

    # Loop as long as the variable ln (line number)
    # is not equal to the first column and insert blank
    # lines.

    # Note: awk will auto-initialize an integer variable
    # with 0 upon its first usage

    while(++ln!=$1) {
        print ln
    }
}

1 # this always expands to true, making awk print the input lines
```

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate you explaining the syntax! I didn't know about using 1 to print input lines

Answer (score 1):

*I've written this logic in python and tested it works, however I need to run this in an environment that doesn't have python.*

In case you want to have running python code where python is not installed you might *freeze* your code. [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/) has overview of tools which are able to do it. I suggest first trying [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) as it support various operation system and seems easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU join, seq and join):

```
join -a1 -t' ' <(seq $(sed -n '$s/ .*//p' file)) file 2>/dev/null
```

Join a file created by the command `seq` using the last line number in `file` with `file`.